# Help designing a voltage ramping circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, circuit-design

I'm trying to design a circuit that starts at 0 Vrms and ramps up to 3.4 Vrms sine wive over five(ish) cycles, then stay at 3.4 Vrms until it's turned off. It doesn't need to ramp back down, however. The period of each cycle is 500 us (2 kHz signal). The load impedance is 200 ohms.

I've looked at the following site (http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4314544/Integrator-ramps-up-down-holds-output-level#id1676356-67-a) and while it looks close, it's using a straight DC signal while mine is alternating and I'm not sure how frequency will effect the output. Any design help or tips or further reading is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google VCA. THAT2181 comes to mind.

Comment: What is load? and wave shape of current? square sine, triangle? You only give Vrms and f, What controls cutoff ? zero voltage or current or don't care, then what is load impedance thus dV/dt or dI/dt

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this. It's a sine wave, cut off is zero voltage I believe and the load impedance is 200 ohms.

Comment: Ok constant R, and zero DC, then harmonic distortion level? and also include in question, is DC offset or lack of DC transient  important?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is the answer you're looking for but one of the engineers here said our harmonic distortion level is 40kHz. DC offset must be zero,lack of DC transient is important.

Comment: no , distortion is a % of output or dB down from fundamental but at harmonics of signal.  unknown application , makes us guess what is important in specs.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not privy to that info, apologies I can't be more clear. I'm still pretty new at this whole electronics thing. Right now this design is proof of concept so we can assume whatever a "good" harmonic distortion level is and work from there. I would say as of right now, harmonic distortion isn't incredibly important as it can be ironed out later (I'd assume)

Comment: OK, then with fuzzy specs, I can only give fuzzy answers.  Linear high Q oscillators ramp up in high number of cycles.  Low startup cycle  implies low Q oscillator or VCA multiplier  using fixed sine and slow rise ramp for 4~5 cycles with product quotient output as per @winny

Comment: Thank you Tony and Winny, I'll look more into VCA's and low Q oscillators then. Much appreciated.

Comment: but low Q also implies higher harmonic distortion for 5 cycles. Perhaps your Eng used DAC with  40kHz sample rate to generate output

Comment: There must be other hidden reasons why you ask? cost? complexity, size?  ALWAYS start any design with better specs.  Some multipliers are logarithmic (Wide range ( like THAT2181) others linear.  But then without knowing complexity, cost, distortion etc specs, many more questions or trial and error.

Comment: Size and cost aren't an issue right now, would prefer to keep complexity to a minimum. I'd love to give more info but unfortunately I'm really unable to. I appreciate your effort in helping me though.

Comment: "Cost isn't a an issue" = any THAT circuit. Very overpriced but easy to implement and low noise.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good application for [direct digital synthesis (DDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesizer) techniques.

Essentially this means writing a computer program (or a digital logic design) to generate digital values representing samples of the desired signal over time. Then use a digital-analog converter (DAC) to translate these to analog voltages. Possibly an analog filter may be used on the output signal to reduce digitization artifacts. And an analog amplifier might be used to increase the output power or voltage capability.

Obviously this is a very high level view. As you've heard from the comments on your question, the details of how this should be implemented (sample rate, sample resolution, filter details) will depend on the particular requirements of your application.

Comment: I'll do some research and see what I can come up with. Thank you!

Comment: This may require a quite expensive high resolution DAC as the digital values have to represent both small and large sine waves. One option is to run an analogue-generated sine wave through a DAC or digital potentiometer to scale it. The 10 bit DACs available on many PIC microcontrollers are ideal for this as they have accessible + and - references and are of the resistor-string type.

Comment: @ShankSinatra - This isn't really a good application of DDS devices. DDS allows easy, precise control of frequency, but not of amplitude. In fact, in most DDS implementations amplitude is fixed by the accumulator length, and the frequency by the rollover of the accumulator.